# Error while executing jar with Crontab

Tags: java, linux, shell, jar, cron

I have a .jar which generates some images and these images are embedded in email and sent.

If I call the jar through shell script and run the script through command line as everything works fine, but if I schedule the script in crontab, jar is failing to create image. Also any kind of exception message is not shown in JAR log.

All the file, folders, jars have all the access.

Please comment if any more details are required.

From the log file, I got following exception message:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:547)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
        at org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame.<init>(ApplicationFrame.java:65)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.deliverymanagerpnp.DeliveryManagerPnPCharts.<init>(DeliveryManagerPnPCharts.java:49)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.deliverymanagerpnp.DeliveryManagerPnPTrends.calculateSBUGraphTrens(DeliveryManagerPnPTrends.java:68)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.dao.WSRTrendDAO.getWeekWiseSBUTrends(WSRTrendDAO.java:256)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.dao.WSRTrendDAO.getAllPnPDetails(WSRTrendDAO.java:152)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.dao.WSRTrendDAO.getOrCodeDetails(WSRTrendDAO.java:65)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.deliverymanagerpes.DeliveryManagerPESBody.setRedFlagsTable(DeliveryManagerPESBody.java:109)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.deliverymanagerpes.DeliveryManagerPESBody.generateBody(DeliveryManagerPESBody.java:64)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.DeliveryManagerPESWSR.generateEmailBody(DeliveryManagerPESWSR.java:129)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.DeliveryManagerPESWSR.sendWSR(DeliveryManagerPESWSR.java:65)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.report.DeliveryManagerPESWSR.sendReport(DeliveryManagerPESWSR.java:30)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.main.WSRmain.sendReport(WSRmain.java:96)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.main.WSRmain.main(WSRmain.java:42)
        at com.kpit.cba.wsr.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Comment: Show the relevant code please. How do you start it in cron?

Comment: Remember that cron only gets a [minimal number of environment variables](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work). Especially check your `PATH` variable. I also suggest that you have your cron entry write a log file, like `0 0 * * *      path/to/your/application >> /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1`

Comment: @Jens  `56 11 * * 2 /home/myuser/myscript.sh` is the statement in cron tab

Comment: @Andreas The jar itself has its own log file. But nothing found in that.

Comment: @SachinMhetre we need the content of the myscript.sh, because like Andreas said you simply might be missing environment variables

Comment: Still, you could use `56 11 * * 2 /home/myuser/myscript.sh >> /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` so that anything which `myscript.sh` would otherwise print on the console goes into a log file - most likely, you will find something like `java: command not found`

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks a lot man, Now I got the actual error in log generated by ur way. The headless exception  is thrown.

Comment: @SachinMhetre Cany you show the code and the stacktrace.

Comment: could you try setting DISPLAY environment variable as is set in a regular terminal before executing your app?

Comment: Go through the "Debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info